# How to configure pip to install a script to the environment bin/ folder?

Tags: python, pip

I'm writing a package in Python, and I want possible users to install a command to their system by installing with `pip`. A package that I want to copy the installation behavior of is [`gdown`](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/blob/main/pyproject.toml). When you install this, a `gdown` python executable is put inside the environment's (whether it's global or a virtual environment) `bin/` folder, so that `gdown` can be called from the command line.

How do I replicate this behavior? I tried to look at the code in the repository but I can't seem to find the code that does this.

Comment: In [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/blob/main/pyproject.toml), look at `[project.scripts]`

Comment: Interesting, thank you! Would you mind explaining what exactly this does, though? Does the script that is installed import the `main` function from `gdown.__main__` automatically? (the local script is something like `from gdown.cli import main... sys.argv[0] = re.replace(..., sys.argv[0]); sys.exit(main())`)

Also funny detail, the owner of the package changed the name of the file from which the `main` function comes from from `cli.py` to `__main__.py` just as I asked this question

Comment: there are 2 ways to do this. the old way is using a `setup.py` file and including an entry_point to your cli `app.py` file. and the new way is using a `pyproject.toml` file and including the entry point under the `[project.scripts]` section. see [pyproject.toml](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/) for more info.

Comment: Do you want to create something like CLI? If so, one of the best tools to do so is [typer](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer) by tiangolo (creator of FastAPI)

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/#creating-executable-scripts